# webpack font can't resolve

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to include font files in my webpack with a bit of difficulty.

**font.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoBlack';
    src: url('./font/Lato-Black.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('./font/Lato-Black.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('./font/Lato-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

**Webpack.base.Config**

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=./font/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.woff$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=./font/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.woff2$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=./font/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.[ot]tf$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=./font/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.eot$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=./font/[name].[ext]' }
    ]
  }
};
```

**Structure**

[image]

**webpack.prod.conf**

```
module.exports = new Config().extend('./webpack.base.config.js').merge({
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  devtool: 'eval',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app/www'),
    publicPath: '/app/www'
  },
});
```

**Error**

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"modules":true,"sourceMap":true,"importLoaders":2,"localIdentName":"[local]_[hash:base64:5]"}!./~/postcss-loader?sourceMap&parser=postcss-scss!./src/components/shared/main.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './font/Lato-ThinItalic.ttf' in '/var/www/kindred/src/components/shared'
 @ ./~/css-loader?{"modules":true,"sourceMap":true,"importLoaders":2,"localIdentName":"[local]_[hash:base64:5]"}!./~/postcss-loader?sourceMap&parser=postcss-scss!./src/components/shared/main.css 6:5744-5781
 @ ./src/components/shared/main.css
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi ./src/index.js
```

**webpack.base.config**

```
/* eslint-disable filenames/match-regex, import/no-commonjs, import/unambiguous */

const path = require('path');
const {environment} = require('webpack-config');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /dashjs\/dist\/.*/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules\/.*/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=25000'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'svg-react-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap',
            query: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 2,
              localIdentName: environment.get('cssIdent')
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader?sourceMap&parser=postcss-scss'
        ],
      },
      // Font Definitions
      { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=./font/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.woff$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=./font/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.woff2$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=./font/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.[ot]tf$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=./font/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.eot$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=./font/[name].[ext]' }
    ]
  }
};
```

So how can I make it load? :O

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Due to having relative webpack is not able to find according to its current location. In the module rules add this and install file-loader

`npm install --save-dev file-loader`

```
{
        test: /\.(svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use:'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: 'images/[name].[hash].[ext]'
       }

},
```

Edit:
Usually relative url can be solved in three ways

-**use absolute path**

-**use options and set url to false**

```
use:[
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {url: false}
        }
    ]
```

-**use raw loder as it will loder url as string**

```
use: ['raw-loader', 'css-loader'],
```

Comment: Thanks pal, however I am still getting the same error as before, I have changed nothing in my `css` files though.

Comment: Thanks pal, i've only just got time to tackel this. Please see update question

Answer (score 7):

**Webpack 5 or later versions**

Don't need any loader installation, just add in `webpack.config.js`.

```
   module: {
    rules: [
      {
       test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
       type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: seems not to be working, could you explain the answer a bit?

Comment: Hi NickN., before webpack-5 we need to install loader and then to use them in order to be able to use fonts. Cause webpack only read javascript, for all other type of files we need to use loaders. (CSS, PNG)...

And from webpack5, we do not need to install any loader to load (use) fonts in webpack. You need to add rules which I wrote before, an then to import font and to add @font-face. 
You can find it here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-fonts

Comment: This is the preferred approach for webpack5. Be sure to use the absolute path to font assets in SASS files.